# Creating wrapper over boost::deadline_timer, not able to pass parameter to handler function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to create a simple `BoostTimer` class which wraps `deadline_timer`'s essential functions such as `async_wait` and `cancel`, so that my program just calls `startTimer` and `killTimer`, I have written following code

### boosttimer.h

```
#ifndef __BOOST_TIMER__
#define __BOOST_TIMER__

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/duration.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

class BoostTimer{
public:
        typedef boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline_timer;
        typedef deadline_timer::duration_type duration;
        typedef boost::function<void (boost::system::error_code, BoostTimer&)> handler_function;

        BoostTimer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, duration interval, handler_function handler);
        ~BoostTimer();

        void startTimer();
        void killTimer();

private:
        deadline_timer _timer;
        boost::asio::io_service& _ioService;
        duration _interval;
        handler_function _handler;
};
#endif
```

### boosttimer.cpp

```
#include "boosttimer.h"

BoostTimer::BoostTimer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, duration interval, handler_function handler) :
        _timer(io_service),
        _ioService(io_service),
        _interval(interval),
        _handler(handler)
{ 
}

BoostTimer::~BoostTimer()
{
}

void BoostTimer::startTimer()
{
        _timer.expires_from_now(_interval);
        _timer.async_wait(boost::bind(_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::ref(*this))); //trying to pass placeholder argument but somehow it doesn't work
}

void BoostTimer::killTimer()
{
        _timer.cancel();
}
```

### timertest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "boosttimer.h"

//void timer_handler(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/) // not able to take parameters
void timer_handler() //it runs fine without parameters 
{
        std::cout<<"timer function has been called" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    BoostTimer timer(io_service,boost::posix_time::seconds(5), boost::bind(&timer_handler));
    timer.startTimer();

    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how can i pass parameters to my handler function from my `BoostTimer` class's `startTimer` function ? I tried it but I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pass arguments from the caller:

```
void timer_handler(std::string const& arg1, int arg2)
{
    std::cout<<"timer function has been called with arg1='" << arg1 <<"', arg2=" << arg2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    BoostTimer timer(io_service,boost::posix_time::seconds(5), boost::bind(&timer_handler, "This is arg1", 42));
    timer.startTimer();

    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d74340b4be2ef191)</kbd>**, output:

```
timer function has been called with arg1='This is arg1', arg2=42
```

To also pass `ec` and `*this`:

> **CAVEAT** I think this seriously breaks any encapsulation and makes the whole class basically redundant. Consider not calling the completion handler in case of cancellation e.g. Also, let the caller bind the objects instances it requires (it's weird for the user-defined handler to require a reference to `BoostTimer` - that's tight coupling in the wrong direction)

```
void timer_handler(boost::system::error_code ec, BoostTimer& instance, std::string const& arg1, int arg2) //it runs fine without parameters 
{
    std::cout<<"timer function has been called with arg1='" << arg1 <<"', arg2=" << arg2 << " (" << ec.message() << ")\n";
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    BoostTimer timer(io_service,boost::posix_time::seconds(1), boost::bind(&timer_handler, _1, _2, "This is arg1", 42));
    timer.startTimer();

    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afab7ebd6e4bad8c)</kbd>** too, output:

```
timer function has been called with arg1='This is arg1', arg2=42 (Success)
```

Comment: it works fine when i am passing 2 parameters while binding `timer_handler` to `BoostTimer`, but what if I only want to pas `ec` and `*this`(e.g. `BoostTimer`), when i remove arguments `arg1` and `arg2`  from `timer_handler` and `_1` and `_2` while creating `BoostTimer`, it starts giving compilation error, any take in this ?

Comment: @Tejendra you must have done something wrong http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94f3e8de93ee2a99

Comment: oh yes, i didn't pass _1 and _2 as parameters, that explains it, thanks mate, and btw I will be following your channel [link](https://www.liveedu.tv/sehe/), it's really helpful

Comment: I prefer to think of `std::bind(callable, _1, _2)` as _binding_ two placeholders, not passing (because that's just the expression template to create the bound callable. You're not _passing_ `_1` or `_2` conceptually). So what the answer showed is that you can _bind_ values or placeholders to an n-ary callable to create an m-ary callable (m<=n)